# Generic method to find greater values fails some tests

Tags: java, methods, collections

I have created a method that finds all values greater than a selected value in a Collection but sometimes it is incorrect. Can anyone see why? These are two instances of failure:

```
 Selector test case - method greater: val less than all elements. 
 java.lang.AssertionError: c = [-5,-2,0,4,8,15,50] val = -99 expected:<true> 
 but was:<false>

 Selector test case - method greater: val equal to elements. 
 java.lang.AssertionError: c = [-5,-2,0,4,8,15,50] val = -5 expected:<true> 
 but was:<false>
```

## Telemeter - for distance

```
 * Defines abstract behavior of distance finding between objects.
 * As a subinterface of Comparator, Telemeter also defines a
 * total order on objects of the type parameter E.
 * 
 *
 *
 * @param <E> the type on which distance and order are defined
 *
 */
public interface Telemeter<E> extends Comparator<E> {

   /**
    * Returns the distance between e1 and e2.
    *
    * @param e1 the first object
    * @param e2 the second object
    * @return the distance between e1 and e2
    *
    */

   public double distance(E e1, E e2);



}
```

### Method for greater values

```
 /**
    * Return a Collection of all the elements of c that are greater than val.
    * If c contains no elements greater than val, this method returns an
    * empty Collection.
    *
    * @param <T> the type variable for this method
    * @param c the Collection to be searched
    * @param val the reference value
    * @param tm the Telemeter that measures distance
    * @return the a Collection of the elements e in c 
    * such that e is greater than val
    *
    */
   public static <T> Collection<T> greater(Collection<T> c, T val, 
      Telemeter<T> tm) {
      if (c == null || c.size() == 0 || tm == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      Collection<T> answer = new ArrayList<T>();
      Iterator<T> a = c.iterator();
      while  (a.hasNext()) {
         if (tm.distance(a.next(), val) < 0) {
            answer.add(a.next());
         }
      }   
      return answer;   




}
```

Comment: Don't ask us to debug for you. Use an IDE's debugger and step through your code if you can't do it directly.

Comment: These are the problems I cant solve after attempts to debug. It used to not work at all.

Comment: _but sometimes it is incorrect_ Use a debugger to find those times and backtrack. Where did that incorrect value come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug is that your are calling `a.next()` *twice* inside the loop - so you are adding the *next* element to the one you compared: Calling `next()` doesn't just return the next element, it advances the iterator too.

But! Your design is all wrong. The generic type of the method should extend *`Comparable`* not `Comparator`. Then you don't need your interface `Telemetet`.

Your method would then simply be:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Collection<T> greater(Collection<T> c, T val) {
    if (c == null || c.size() == 0 || val == null) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    Collection<T> answer = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T a : c) {
       if (val.compareTo(a) < 0) {
           answer.add(a);
       }
    }   
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very incomplete, and the notion of "distance" is misleading (distances are generally supposed to be non-negative). But one thing that could cause wrong results is that you are calling a.next() twice, which will advance the iterator twice (if the condition is true) in the same "while" iteration.